# How To Add New fxml to Controller

Tags: java, javafx, builder

I have 2 `.fxml` files (`FXMLDocument.fxml`/`login.fxml`) and one controller file (`FXMLDocumentController`). I want to remove `FXMLDocument.fxml` from the controller and add `login.fxml` to the contoller.

When I call the main method, I want get prompted with the login form instead of `FXMLDocument.fxml`.

Any idea what is happening?

**PS:** `login.fxml` is created using **[SceneBuilder](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/javafxscenebuilder-info-2157684.html)**.

Comment: "I have 2 FXML files and one controller". Don't. Each FXML file should have its own controller class.

Comment: can it replace? .i mean `FXMLDocument.fxml` is generated by IDE.`login.fxml` created by me using scene builder i dont want to IDE genrated fxml insted of that i want to replce my login.fxml.

Comment: Sorry, what are you asking? What does "can it replace?" mean? (Can  *what* replace  *what*?) Just specify a different controller class in each FXML file.

Comment: can FXMLDocument.fxml replace with login.fxml

Comment: Sorry. I simply do not understand what that means.

Comment: when i created my JavaFx project IDE generated this 3 Files(`FXMLDocument.fxml/FXMLDocumentContoller.java/main.java`) .when i run this it pop some dialog box that is the default behavior.i have another file fxml (`login.fxml`)file that is created by me  using Scene Builder .i dont want this `FXMLDocument.fxml` instead of that i want to connect `login.fxml`. when i run main want to get  `login.fxml` window .English is not my mother tongue sorry for the inconvenience .

Comment: Just change which FXML file is loaded by the main class. I don't understand the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to use the default FXML file generated by your IDE. Here is a basic controller that will use login.fxml:

```
public class LoginController {

    public LoginController(){
        try {
            FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("login.fxml"));
            fxmlLoader.setController(this);
            fxmlLoader.load();
        } catch (IOException exception) {
            System.out.println("Error loading content.");
            System.exit(0);
        }
    }

}
```

Note the line with `FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("login.fxml"))`. This is how you add an FXML file to a controller.